# How to handle File Input in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

As **there is no helper for File Input**, how can we safely handle a file input?

If it better just to have a button

```
<input type="button" value="Upload File" />
```

and handle this in a new pop-up page/window?

shall I have the

```
<input type="file" value="Upload File" />
```

but how would I handle this in the code?

```
#region General
//
// GET: /Content/General
public ActionResult General()
{
    GeneralModel model = new GeneralModel();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public void General(GeneralModel model)
{

}

#endregion
```

The model **will not be populated** with the file so I need to do something else ... just don't know what :(

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input should have a name:

```
<input type="file" name="File" />
```

Then to handle the uploaded file you could add a property to your view model:

```
public class GeneralModel
{
    // The name of the property corresponds to the name of the input
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and finally in your controller action handle the file upload:

```
[HttpPost]
public void General(GeneralModel model)
{
    var file = model.File;
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // The user selected a file to upload => handle it
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }
    return View(model);    
}
```

Phil Haack [blogged](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) about file uploads in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks, you just forgot that I need `<% using (Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post, 
   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>` :)

Comment: I thought that was obvious :-) `multipart/form-data` is always required for file uploads.

Comment: I do have to handle 2 forms right? one for images and other for the rest of the properties...?

Comment: Not necessarily. One form can handle for both file uploads and normal inputs as long as you have the correct `enctype`.

Comment: Got it, it handles everything :) many thanks for the heads up.